# Is it possible to programmatically call a telephone number in JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

So basically right now I can create a button with an A tag that has an href="tel:XXXXXXXXXXX" and if a user clicks / taps on that it will bring them into their phone application. However I am trying to do this programmatically on gesture recognition (swipe). The gesture is working, so far I have tried `window.location = "tel:XXXXXXXXXX";
window.open('tel:XXXXXXXXXX', '_top');`

neither of which have worked yet. Any idea? Ionic / Angular 1

Note** It appears to only happen on iOS, Android seems to be working fine.

Comment: Try making an `a` element, setting the `href`, and then firing a click event on it.  Not sure if that will work or not, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I just tried, it seems to grab the element correctly. But casting js .click() does not seem to trigger it

Comment: Did you include country code? Do you have handlers set for the protocol? See https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-telephone-links/ , https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html

Answer (score 14):

If you want to do it through html, then you just have to place a tag like this:

```
<a href="tel:XXXXXXXXXX">Call me!</a>
```

similarly if you wanna do it through javascript, you can do:

```
document.location.href = "tel:XXXXXXXXXX";
```

Comment: This solution did not work on iPhone/Safari

Answer (score 9):

For this you will require to add this in the config.xml first

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

then call it like:

```
document.location.href = "tel:XXXXXXXXXX";
```

[Whitelist Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html#Whitelist%20Guide)

Comment: This works. Also with "sms:*". Together with using <allow-intent href="tel:*"/> and <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />

Answer (score 3):

You probably just can't, when your APP is running from mobile browser. You'll need to wrap your app as cordova app or similar. Then you can for example use [PhoneGap-PhoneDialer](https://github.com/anemitoff/PhoneGap-PhoneDialer/blob/0aef448287b8778d435d933037d90445ddb10133/README.md)

Answer (score 2):

You can try with below one,

```
window.location.href = "tel:+91123456789";
```

But, for IOS it may not work because of some permission issues. In that case you can try like below,

```
window.open('tel:+91123456789', '_system');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it on a real device.

None of these methods worked on the IOS emulator. It only worked on a physical device. That tripped me up for a while.