# How to direct a webpage to Make a Call Dialog in web browser?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webbrowser-control, http-redirect

I have seen links when clicked tel:+1123456789 will invoke a call over phone/computer

I have come across some links like

> https://ctrlq.org/call/9876543210

when clicked it will directly invoke make a call without even opening a page.

How is that possible?

PLease note that there is no manual hyperlink clicking involved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examining the header response for the link you shared there is a 302 redirect with a new location `tel:9876543210` which is prompting the browser to *call* the number.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Tue, 06 Oct 2020 15:42:10 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: tel:9876543210
Cache-Control: max-age=600
Expires: Tue, 06 Oct 2020 15:52:10 GMT
Vary: User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 20
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

If you are running an Apache server you can consult the [Apache .htaccess Tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html) and the [Apache URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). If your site is hosted on a server running other software, check with your hoster for more details.

Browser based solutions also exist for setting up redirects, some of which are [covered in this post](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-redirect-to-another-web-page-using-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

From @mhawksey s answer I could do this and it will successfully redirect

Use this link for passing number: [https://yoursite.com/redirect.htm?tel=+1234567890](https://yoursite.com/redirect.htm?tel=%201234567890)

Upload this file to your drive root.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
<body onload='window.location = "tel:" + new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get("tel");'>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand what you mean by no manual hyperlink clicking. But if u need a link that could invoke making a call, u can use anchor tag with tel attribute.

```
<a href="tel:987654321">Call 987654321</a>
```

Comment: U can have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40333051/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-call-a-telephone-number-in-js/40494562